# How to send arrays between threads using pipes?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have three threads - the first one reads sentences until ";" is given, the second counts the characters in those sentences, and the third shows the result.

Well, I've done this for only one sentence, but sending arrays through pipes seems to generate some problems (as well as reading multiple strings from a thread).

For reading, I can put the string only once, and no more. Even mutex on the whole function doesn't work. Why is that so?

Also, after writing the string I get "write: Success" message.

What's wrong here?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

int first[2];
int second[2];

void *input(void *ptr)
{
   char str[100], ch = '0';
   int length, i = 0;

   while(1)
   {
      while(ch != ';')
      {
         printf("Enter the %d message: ", i + 1);
         fflush(stdout);
         length = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof(str));

         if(write(first[1], str, sizeof(str)) != length)
         {
            perror("write");
            exit(2);
         }  

     if(length <= 0)
         {
            if(length == -1)
               perror("read");
            close(first[1]);
            exit(2);
         }

         i++;
      }
   }
}

void *countChars(void *ptr)
{
   char str[100];
   int length, count = 0, i = 0;

   while(1)
   {
      length = read(first[0], str, sizeof(str));

      if(length <= 0)
      {
         if(length == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[0]);
         close(second[1]);
         exit(2);
      }
      if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, length) != length)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }

      while(str[count] != '\n') count++;

      write(second[1], &count, sizeof(count));

      count = 0;
   }
}

void *output(void *ptr)
{
   int length, count = 0, i = 0;

   while(1)
   {
      length = read(second[0], &count, sizeof(count));
      if(length < sizeof(count))
      {
         close(second[0]);
         exit(2);
      }

      printf("Number of characters: %d\n", count);
   }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t t1, t2, t3;

   if(pipe(first) == -1)
   {
      printf("First pipe error");
      exit(1);
   }

   if(pipe(second) == -1)
   {
      printf("Second pipe error");
      exit(1);
   }

   pthread_create(&t1, NULL, input, NULL);
   pthread_create(&t2, NULL, countChars, NULL);
   pthread_create(&t3, NULL, output, NULL);

   pthread_join(t1, NULL);
   pthread_join(t2, NULL);
   pthread_join(t3, NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT.

I think the question would be - how to logically solve this? I see it that way:

```
Thread1 -> (string) -> Thread2 -> (number of chars) -> Thread3 - save elements somewhere
...
Thread1 -> (ending string) -> Thread2 -> (number of chars removed later) -> Thread3 - display all elements
```

BUT if so then - how to make threads run one by one like this? How to stop the application on ending string? Where to save those integer values in thread 3?

Comment: off topic: Why is everything downvoted?

Comment: good question, no idea

Comment: Please edit you question clearly stating your problem. Do you want to fix the logic or the "Write: Success"? Because the way you send data through pipe is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes are used to communicate data between *processes*, not *threads*. Threads run in the same process and have access to the same memory so it is pointless to use pipes in that case.

An example of a pipeline with three processes. Parent sends "hello world" to child, who prepends the string length and sends that new string to the grandchild who prints it to stdout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void parent(int fd_write) {
    char *msg = "hello world";
    ssize_t len = strlen(msg);
    if (write(fd_write, msg, len) != len) {perror("parent write"); exit(1);}
}

void child(int fd_read, int fd_write) {
    char msg_in[100], msg_out[150];
    ssize_t len = read(fd_read, msg_in, sizeof msg_in);
    if (len == -1) {perror("child read"); exit(1);}
    msg_in[len] = '\0';
    len = sprintf(msg_out, "%d: %s", (int)len, msg_in);
    if (write(fd_write, msg_out, len) != len) {perror("child write"); exit(1);}
}

void grandchild(int fd_read) {
    char msg[256];
    ssize_t len = read(fd_read, msg, sizeof msg);
    if (len == -1) {perror("grandchild read"); exit(1);}
    msg[len] = '\0';
    printf("Msg: %s\n", msg);
}

int main() {
    enum {READ, WRITE};
    pid_t pid;

    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {perror("first pipe"); exit(1);}

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {perror("first fork"); exit(1);}

    if (pid == 0) {
        int fd2[2];
        if (pipe(fd2) == -1) {perror("second pipe"); exit(1);}

        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {perror("second fork"); exit(1);}

        if (pid == 0) {
            close(fd2[WRITE]);
            grandchild(fd2[READ]);
            close(fd2[READ]);
            exit(0);
        }

        close(fd[WRITE]); close(fd2[READ]);
        child(fd[READ], fd2[WRITE]);
        close(fd[READ]); close(fd2[WRITE]);
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    }

    close(fd[READ]);
    parent(fd[WRITE]);
    close(fd[WRITE]);
    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very true. If anything, you might pass a pointer to the array via a pipe (which will be valid in another thread of the same process), not the actual array. But even that can be done more efficiently without pipes. You really only want pipes for process-process, not thread-thread.

Comment: The downvoters aren't expressing the reason for their disagreement.

Comment: IMO you did not answer the question you just changed OP's program to suit your opinion on the use of pipes, an opinion I think wrong for many applications.

Comment: @TranslucentPain Fair enough. Thank you for commenting. I just didn't see the sense of pipes in the OP's case. I thought maybe he meant to create a normal pipeline. But he could just be playing with threads and pipes.

Answer (score 1):

In the input thread, after the read call `length = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof(str));`, you are writing `sizeof(str)` and not of size `length`.

It should be

```
if(write(first[1], str, length) != length)
```

Another issue is your code is not matching your specification.
You say that input thread is reading until ';', but `ch` is never modified in the loop. Fix your code.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't see that one, thanks. But if so, the loop should be going forever, yet it stops after the first run.

Comment: It stops after first run, because you have exit on failure. But because of incorrect length matching, even succeess case entered the failure path and printed 'write: Success"!